# How to validate ALL fields in a form with jQuery validate?

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I have an HTML form validated with jQuery validate.
Where "#dati" is the form.
Then, when *success* function results true a button (#prossimaDomanda), which is a Swiper button for sliding next, should be released from the "disabled" class and prop. When jQuery validates just the first field the success function results true and the button released. But I need this to happens only when **all** fields are validated.
Thank you all.

```
        <form method="post" action="?mode=invia" id="dati" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div id="reportErrori"></div>
      <div class="swiper-container">
        <div>
          <?php include("include/inc_navbar_front.php")?>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="colonna">
              <p class="istruzioni" id="test"><strong><?php echo $suffisso ?></strong>Dopo aver inserito i tuoi dati, compila il <strong>questionario</strong><br />
                Riceverai il mio <strong>preventivo</strong> tramite email. </p>
            </div>
            <div class="colonna">
              <div class="form-question">
                <label for="n2">Nome azienda</label>
                <input type="text" id="n2" name="nomeAzienda">
              </div>
              <div class="form-question">
                <label for="n3">Indirizzo</label>
                <input type="text" id="n3" name="indirizzo" >
              </div>
              <div class="flex">
                <div>
                  <div class="miniDomanda">
                    <label for="n4">Città</label>
                    <input type="text" id="n4"name="citta">
                  </div>
                  <div class="miniDomanda">
                    <label for="n5">Cap</label>
                    <input type="text" id="n5" name="cap" >
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <div class="miniDomanda">
                    <label for="n6">Provincia</label>
                    <input type="text" id="n6" name="provincia">
                  </div>
                  <div class="miniDomanda">
                    <label for="n7">P.IVA</label>
                    <input type="text" id="n7" name="partitaIva" >
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-question">
                <label for="n8">Indirizzo email</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="n8">
              </div>
                 <!--FORM immagini-->
              <div class="form-question" id="immagini">
                 <label for="contenitore-immagini">Immagine<br />
                 <span style="font-size: 14px; font-style: italic; font-weight: 400; ">(puoi inserirne al massimo 3)</span></label>
                <div class="immagini" id="contenitore-immagini"> 
                  <div class="newUpload" id="wrapButton">
                    <label for="immagineNuova" id="labelAggiungi">Aggiungi una foto</label>
                    <input type="file" id="immagineNuova" name="immagine[]" />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
             </div>
          </div>
            
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <h2>Il sondaggio durerà circa 30 minuti. Puoi seguire i progressi dalla barra sottostante</h2>
        </div>
            
          <?php
            if ( $domande ) {
            $k = 1;
            foreach ( $domande as $row ) {
          ?>
          <div class="swiper-slide slide-domanda">
            <div class="form-question">
                <h2>Domanda numero <strong><?php echo $k ?></strong></h2>
              <label for="n5" class="areaTesto"><?php echo $row['testo_domanda']?></label>
              <input type="hidden" name="id_domanda[]"  data-counter="<?php echo $k?>" value="<?php echo $row['id_domanda']?>">
              <textarea name="testo_risposta[]" id="contattiPrincipali" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
            </div>
              <?php if ($k == $contaDomande){?>
                 <div class="button-wrapper">
                    <button type="submit">Invia sondaggio</button>
                 </div>
              <?php } ?>
          </div>
          <?php
                $k++;
            };
          };
          ?>
        </div>
          
        <div class="button-wrapper">
          <button type="button" class="swiper-button-next disabled" disabled id="prossimaDomanda"><span class="fa fa-chevron-right"></span></button>
        </div> 
        <div class="button-wrapper">
          <button type="button" class="swiper-button-prev precedenteDomanda" id="precedenteDomanda"><span class="fa fa-chevron-left"></span></button>
        </div>
          
      </div>
      <?php
      };
      };
      ?>
    </form>

var n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8;
    
function valore (selettore){
    return $(selettore).val();
}

    $("#n2").on("change", function(){
        n2 = valore("#n2");
        console.log(n2);

    })
    $("#n3").on("change", function(){
        n3 = valore("#n3");
        console.log(n3);

    })
    $("#n4").on("change", function(){
        n4 = valore("#n4");
        console.log(n4);

    })
    $("#n5").on("change", function(){
        n5 = valore("#n5");
        console.log(n5);

    })
    $("#n6").on("change", function(){
        n6 = valore("#n6");
        console.log(n6);

    })
    $("#n7").on("change", function(){
        n7 = valore("#n7");
        console.log(n7);

    })
    $("#n8").on("change", function(){
        n8 = valore("#n8");
        console.log(n7);

    })
    

    $("#dati").validate({
        
        rules:{
            
            nomeAzienda:{
                required: true,
                remote:{
                    url: "include/cms_ajax_pagina.php?mode=valida",
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {n2: n2}
                },
                pattern:  /^(?=.{2,}$)(([0-9a-zA-ZàáâäãåąčćęèéêëėįìíîïłńòóôöõőøùúûüųūűÿýżźñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅĄĆČĖĘÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏĮŁŃÒÓÔÖÕŐØÙÚÛÜŲŪŰŸÝŻŹÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð ,\.\'\-\?\:])?(?!))+$/            },
            indirizzo:{
                required: true,
                remote:{
                    url: "include/cms_ajax_pagina.php?mode=valida",
                        type: 'post',
                    data: {n3: n3}
                    
                },
                pattern: /^(?=.{2,}$)(([0-9a-zA-ZàáâäãåąčćęèéêëėįìíîïłńòóôöõőøùúûüųūűÿýżźñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅĄĆČĖĘÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏĮŁŃÒÓÔÖÕŐØÙÚÛÜŲŪŰŸÝŻŹÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð ,\.\'\-\?\:])?(?!))+$/         },
            cap:{
                required: true,
                remote:{
                    url: "include/cms_ajax_pagina.php?mode=valida",
                        type: 'post',
                    data: {n4: n4}
                    
                },
                pattern: /^(?=.{2,}$)(([0-9a-zA-ZàáâäãåąčćęèéêëėįìíîïłńòóôöõőøùúûüųūűÿýżźñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅĄĆČĖĘÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏĮŁŃÒÓÔÖÕŐØÙÚÛÜŲŪŰŸÝŻŹÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð ,\.\'\-\?\:])?(?!))+$/         },
            citta:{
                required: true,
                remote:{
                    url: "include/cms_ajax_pagina.php?mode=valida",
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {n5: n5}
                },
                pattern: /^(?=.{2,}$)(([0-9a-zA-ZàáâäãåąčćęèéêëėįìíîïłńòóôöõőøùúûüųūűÿýżźñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅĄĆČĖĘÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏĮŁŃÒÓÔÖÕŐØÙÚÛÜŲŪŰŸÝŻŹÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð ,\.\'\-\?\:])?(?!))+$/         },  
            provincia:{
                required: true,
                remote:{
                    url: "include/cms_ajax_pagina.php?mode=valida",
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {n6: n6}
                },
                pattern: /^(?=.{2,}$)(([0-9a-zA-ZàáâäãåąčćęèéêëėįìíîïłńòóôöõőøùúûüųūűÿýżźñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅĄĆČĖĘÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏĮŁŃÒÓÔÖÕŐØÙÚÛÜŲŪŰŸÝŻŹÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð ,\.\'\-\?\:])?(?!))+$/         },
            partitaIva:{
                required: true,
                remote:{
                    url: "include/cms_ajax_pagina.php?mode=valida",
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {n7: n7}
                },
                pattern: /^(?=.{2,}$)(([0-9a-zA-ZàáâäãåąčćęèéêëėįìíîïłńòóôöõőøùúûüųūűÿýżźñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅĄĆČĖĘÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏĮŁŃÒÓÔÖÕŐØÙÚÛÜŲŪŰŸÝŻŹÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð ,\.\'\-\?\:])?(?!))+$/         },  
            email:{
                required: true,
                remote:{
                    url: "include/cms_ajax_pagina.php?mode=valida",
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {n8: n8}
                    
                },
                pattern: /^(([a-zA-Z]|[0-9])|([-]|[_]|[.]))+[@](([a-zA-Z0-9])|([-])){2,63}[.](([a-zA-Z0-9]){2,63})+$/           },
            
        },
        messages:{
            
            nomeAzienda:{
                required: "Campo obbligatorio",
                pattern:  "Caratteri ammessi: alfanumerici, accentate latine, spazio. Simboli ammessi: trattino(-), apostrofo ('), virgola(,), punto(.),punto interrogativo(?).",
                remote: "Remote ko"
            },
            indirizzo:{
                required: "Campo obbligatorio",
                pattern:  "Caratteri ammessi: alfanumerici, accentate latine, spazio. Simboli ammessi: trattino(-), apostrofo ('), virgola(,), punto(.),punto interrogativo(?).",
                remote: "Remote ko"
            },
            cap:{
                required: "Campo obbligatorio",
                pattern:  "Caratteri ammessi: alfanumerici, accentate latine, spazio. Simboli ammessi: trattino(-), apostrofo ('), virgola(,), punto(.),punto interrogativo(?).",
                remote: "Remote ko"
            },
            citta:{
                required: "Campo obbligatorio",
                pattern:  "Caratteri ammessi: alfanumerici, accentate latine, spazio. Simboli ammessi: trattino(-), apostrofo ('), virgola(,), punto(.),punto interrogativo(?).",
                remote: "Remote ko"
            },  
            provincia:{
                required: "Campo obbligatorio",
                pattern:  "Caratteri ammessi: alfanumerici, accentate latine, spazio. Simboli ammessi: trattino(-), apostrofo ('), virgola(,), punto(.),punto interrogativo(?).",
                remote: "Remote ko"
            },
            partitaIva:{
                required: "Campo obbligatorio",
                pattern:  "Caratteri ammessi: alfanumerici, accentate latine, spazio. Simboli ammessi: trattino(-), apostrofo ('), virgola(,), punto(.),punto interrogativo(?).",
                remote: "Remote ko"
            },  
            email:{
                required: "Campo obbligatorio",
                pattern:  "Inserisci un email valido.",
                remote: "Remote ko",
            }
        },
        invalidHandler: function(event, validator){
            
            $("#prossimaDomanda").addClass("disabled");
            $("#prossimaDomanda").prop("disabled", true);
            console.log("form ko");
        },
                
        success: function(){
            
            $("#prossimaDomanda").removeClass("disabled");
            $("#prossimaDomanda").prop("disabled", false);
            
            
        },
        
        errorPlacement:function(error, element){
        
            var campo = element.parent();
            
            campo.css("position", "relative");
            $(".error-container").appendTo(campo);
            error.appendTo($(".error-container"));
            $(".error-container").fadeIn(300);
            
            setTimeout(function(){
                $(".error-container").fadeOut(1000);
                
                setTimeout(function(){
                    
                    campo.css("position", "static")
                    $(".error-container").empty();
                    $(".error-container").appendTo("body");}, 1500)
                
            }, 4000);
        },
    
        submitHandler: function(form){
            
        $(form).submit();
      }
    })
```

EDIT:
Here is the little php code started via AJAX that is quite working, but its not so stable. Sometimes, when I click on autocomplete I encounter the same problem.

```
  if ( $mode == "validazione" ) {

      foreach($_POST as $risposta){
          
          echo (isset($risposta)) ? "true" : "false";
      }
}
```

ANOTHER EDIT:

Finally, I just wrote another little script. Maybe its too verbose, but it works by now.

```
function validaMioBottone (element){
    
    var str = element.val();
    
    if(str.length > 0){
    
      var reg = new RegExp("(?=.{2,}$)(([0-9a-zA-ZàáâäãåąčćęèéêëėįìíîïłńòóôöõőøùúûüųūűÿýżźñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅĄĆČĖĘÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏĮŁŃÒÓÔÖÕŐØÙÚÛÜŲŪŰŸÝŻŹÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð ,\.\'\-\?\:])\2?(?!\2))+$")
      var res = reg.test(str);
        
      return res
        
    } else {
      return 
    }
}

var numeroOk = 0;
    
$("#dati input").each(function(){
    $(this).on("change", function(){
        if( validaMioBottone($(this)) == true ){
            if($(this).hasClass("validato")){
                    return 
                } else{
                    numeroOk++
                    $(this).addClass("validato");
                }
                
            } else{
                
                if($(this).hasClass("validato")){
                    numeroOk--
                    $(this).removeClass("validato")
                } else{
                    return
                }
            }
            
            if(numeroOk == 7){
                    
                $("#prossimaDomanda").removeClass("disabled");
                $("#prossimaDomanda").prop("disabled", false);
                
            } else{
                $("#prossimaDomanda").addClass("disabled");
                $("#prossimaDomanda").prop("disabled", true);
                
            }
            
            console.log(numeroOk);
        })
        
    })
```

Comment: First, show us the actual RENDERED code, not the PHP.  Secondly, where is the HTML of the form?

Comment: *"... success function results true and the button released.  I need this to happens only when all fields are validated."* - obviously the `success` callback is not the right place since it's called each time a single field is valid.  Try the `submitHandler` since it's only called when the entire form is valid.

Answer (score -1):

```
 $( "#register_form" ).validate({
        rules: {
          password: {
                minlength: 8
          },
          email: {
              remote: {
                  url: '{% url "check_email_notexists" %}',   <--- you can also make an ajax call like this.
                  type: 'GET'
              }
          },
          username: {
              minlength: 3,
              maxlength: 25,
              remote: {
                  url: '{% url "check_username_notexists" %}',
                  type: 'GET'
              }
            },
            confirm_password: {
                minlength: 8,
                equalTo: "#password"
          }
        },
        errorElement: 'small',
        
        messages: {
            first_name: {
                required: "Please enter First Name"
            },
            last_name: {
                required: "Please enter Last Name"
            },
            username: {
                required: "Please provide a username",
                remote: 'Username already exists'
            },
            email: {
                required: "Please provide an email",
                remote: 'Email already exist'
            },
            password: {
                minlength: jQuery.validator.format("At least {0} characters required!"),
                required: "Please enter Password"
            },
            confirm_password: {
                required: "Please enter Password",
                equalTo: "Password did not match"
          }
        }
  });
```

I'm using this in one of my jquery project.